# AngularJS - Modified object does not carry from one test to the next

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

So I have this simple object in the `service` of my AngularJS app:

```
    this.testObj = [
        {'id': 0, 'label': 'Hello'}
    ];
```

called inside from `.service('MainSvc', function () {`

and in the controller, I have:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope, MainSvc) {
    this.testObj = MainSvc.testObj;
});
```

The thing is, I am doing Karma/Jasmine tests and it goes well until the 2nd test ... it does not recognize the object has changed and gets it new.

It's a mocked unit test.

```
describe('Mocked Unit Test', function() {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('main'));

    var MainSvc, scope, http, mockMain;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, MainSvc, $controller, $injector){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        mockMain = $injector.get('MainSvc');

        $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            MainSvc: mockMain
        });

        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should expect item to be defined', inject(function() {
        expect(mockMain.testObj).toBeDefined(); // passes
        mockMain.testObj[1] = {id: 2, label: "World"};
        console.log(mockMain.testObj); // [Object{id: 0, label: 'Hello'}, Object{id: 2, label: 'World'}]
        console.log('Length: ' + Object.keys(mockMain.testObj).length); // Length: 2
    }));

    it('expect the testObj object to have a 2nd index', inject(function() {
        console.log(mockMain.testObj); // [Object{id: 0, label: 'Hello'}]
        console.log('Length: ' + Object.keys(mockMain.testObj).length); // Length: 1

        // Where is testObj[1] from when it was added in the first test?
    }));
});
```

As you can see, from the in-line comments, that the object in the second `it()` test does not see that the object of `mockMain.testObj` has changed.

Or maybe I am refrencing it wrong?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I believe each it() has it's own scope and mocked objects, so the changes from one test to the other won't carry, as that would defy the unitness of the unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests do not depend on each other, they are isolated. That is one of the main unit-testing principles. If you want to have something common between two tests, you should use `beforeEach()`:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, MainSvc, $controller, $injector){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    mockMain = $injector.get('MainSvc');

    $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        MainSvc: mockMain
    });

    mockMain.testObj[1] = {id: 2, label: "World"};
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should expect item to be defined', inject(function() {
    expect(mockMain.testObj).toBeDefined(); // passes
    console.log(mockMain.testObj); 
    console.log('Length: ' + Object.keys(mockMain.testObj).length); // Length: 2
}));

it('expect the testObj object to have a 2nd index', inject(function() {
    console.log(mockMain.testObj); 
    console.log('Length: ' + Object.keys(mockMain.testObj).length); 
}));
```

Or you can add another `describe` block and use `beforeEach()` there:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, MainSvc, $controller, $injector){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    mockMain = $injector.get('MainSvc');

    $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        MainSvc: mockMain
    });

    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should expect item to be defined', inject(function() {
    expect(mockMain.testObj).toBeDefined(); // passes
    mockMain.testObj[1] = {id: 2, label: "World"};
    console.log(mockMain.testObj); // [Object{id: 0, label: 'Hello'}, Object{id: 2, label: 'World'}]
    console.log('Length: ' + Object.keys(mockMain.testObj).length); // Length: 2
}));

describe('having two elements in the array', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        mockMain.testObj[1] = {id: 2, label: "World"};
    });

    it('expect the testObj object to have a 2nd index', inject(function() {
        console.log(mockMain.testObj); 
        console.log('Length: ' + Object.keys(mockMain.testObj).length); 
    }));

});
```

Also, it seems to be wrong to assert on something that you have defined in the test. By setting second element in the array, and then testing its length, you are just verifying native javascript assignment.